# Azure static website deployed to Azure CDN has static chunk files returning 404

Tags: azure, blob, azure-web-app-service, cdn, azure-cdn

I have a working azure blob static website react app. I have tried to set up an Azure CDN for it, which I had working with HTTPS enabled. I then deployed an update to the static website, which continues to work, but now some of the /static/* js and css files return 404 when loading from the CDN endpoint (while still working from the static website). I've tried redeploying, I've tried purging the files in question from the CDN, and I've tried waiting overnight. They still don't seem to resolve. Is there a setting or configuration I accidentally miffed up or forgot somewhere?

[image]

Comment: CDNs are supposed to be quick with file pick ups. Have you checked if the files in question are available on the connected storage?

Comment: @SunnySharma files are there and the page loads fine when loaded via the azure blob static website url - just missing when accessed via the CDN (Akamai)

Comment: For Azure CDN Standard from Akamai profiles, propagation usually completes within one minute. Please use the link shared by Sajeethkaran below and troubleshoot the possible bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Azure CDN (Verizon Standard) and usually takes 24 hours for the images/files to pull up using the Endpoint Hostname. However you can use this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-troubleshoot-endpoint) to troubleshoot the errors.